# Is there an event to detect when the screen dims?

Tags: android

I'm using a SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK and so my never turns off. It just goes from full brightness to dim.

Is there any way for me to detect when the screen gets dim (event, receiver, etc.) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see from Android's source code, there is no broadcast notification send when screen brightness state is changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a WakeLock in order to make your screen dim. You can check if the WakeLock is aquired by using the .isHeld() method.

Answer (score -1):

Get the screen Timeout and then take like -5 seconds