# Android: How to get information if screen goes to dimming mode?

Tags: android, screen

I want to receive a message when the backlight of the LCD is switched off ( or is it dimmed ). You know in Android settings you can define the screen Timeout.
For example after 15 seconds the screen goes in a dim mode.
I have developed an app which have a lot of buttons on the main activity. If the display start's to dim, and a user is touch on the screen, it's very often that he hits a button and the OnClick Methode of this button will called.
This i want to avoid. So therfore i want to receive some message when the display is starting to go into the dim mode. Then i will just disable all buttons , when the display is leaving the dim mode i want to enable the buttons.

With registing an BroadcastReceiver i can get the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF and ACTION_SCREEN_ON messages. But this messages won't be send when the LCD goes to dim mode.
If found also a message called ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED but also this message i do not receive when the LCD goes to dim mode..

```
 IntentFilter myfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    myfilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    myfilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED);
    myfilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, myfilter);
```

...

```
    public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // thanks Jason
    public  boolean wasScreenOn = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "SOMETHING ");
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = false;
            Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED");

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            wasScreenOn = true;
            Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_DREAMING_STOPPED");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you go against Android's way? If the screen is dimming out but the user interacts with it before it went off, Android wakes it up and takes the user's input. Even if you refuse to execute any action then, the screen will still wake up, would'nt it? Anyway, going for a `Receiver` with those `Intent` is the right direction.

Comment: with this buttons, a receipt for a POS application will be printed. 
I don't want to stay always the screen on ( that could also be a way ) .
But naturally if a LCD is dimmed, before I start to work with the device users will press on it. If he hit's a button a receipt is printed...That i want to avoid...

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. I'm afraid such broadcast does not exist in Android after all: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6005334/603270

Comment: ok thanks a lot  
the last post on the thread could be a possibility...