# how to get Screen dim events in android

Tags: android, screen-brightness

I want to get the dim state of the screen from bright,but I don't know how.
  there are broadcast for screen_on and screen_off,but there is no broadcast for screen_dim,is there any way to get screen_dim?
the following way doesn't work:
  save value at the beginning and check whether the number change afterwards doesn't work,because the return values are always the same and return -1(default value)
  WindowManager.LayoutParams lpcurrent = getWindow().getAttributes();     if(lpcurrent.screenBrightness==brightAtBeginning) // do something

Comment: As far as I can see from Android's source code, there is no broadcast notification send when screen brightness state is changed. refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916213/is-there-an-event-to-detect-when-the-screen-dims

Comment: yeah 3q,i don't know either